# In auto-layout scrollview setContentOffset not working correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, autolayout

I am working with fully auto-layout.

Last `UITextField` (end of the view before done button): I set `setContentOffset` in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`, it works fine but when I try to scroll (at keyboard shown), `UIScrollView` is back to normal.

Then text field back to keyboard. Here my code at `textFieldDidBeginEditing`.

I am using `bskeyboardcontroller` for next and previous and done button.

```
[self.scrollviewDetail setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 500) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is your Scroll view height on KeyBoard appearance in View, simply you change scroll insects or frame to avoid this problem, if scroll view content offset greater than (content size - scroll view frame size) while scroll it will reset automatically in Scroll view.

Try this code :

```
  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    }

    - (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

        CGRect keyboardRect = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
        keyboardRect = [self.view convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil];

        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardRect.size.height, 0.0);
        scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardRect.size.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, currentTextField.frame.origin) ) {
        [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:currentTextField.frame animated:NO];
    }
    }
    - (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification
    {

        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    }
```